# Timed Convert to Shared Mailbox Rule

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, system-administration

I've always been curious about this. As a SysAdmin, I frequently receive requests to convert users to shared mailboxes once they've submitted a 2 week notice.

When that happens I retain their request until the 2 weeks are up then remove the user's license and convert them to a shared mailbox using the EAC.

Is there any way to schedule that sort of function in advance, possibly with a PS Script?